# Fragments not added to backstack using Navigation Components

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

### Information:

I'm programmatically inserting a `NavHostFragment` for each feature of the app. Each `NavHostFragment` has it's own Navigation Graph. Dagger is providing them by using a `FragmentFactory` specific to each feature. It's a **Single Activity** structure with MVVM architecture.

Repo: https://github.com/mitchtabian/DaggerMultiFeature/tree/nav-component-backstack-bug

**checkout the branch "nav-component-backstack-bug".**

---

### The Problem

When navigating into the graph the fragments are not being added to the backstack. The only fragment that's added is whichever one has most recently been visited. **So the stack size always stays at one.**

Originally I thought it was because I wasn't setting the `FragmentFactory` to the `ChildFragmentManager` but that doesn't change anything. See the code snippets below for the relevant code. Or checkout the project and run it. I have logs printing out the fragments currently in the backstack from the `ChildFragmentManager` and also the `SupportFragmentManager`. Both have a constant size of 1.

---

**Feature1NavHostFragment.kt**

This is one of the custom `NavHostFragment`'s. The `create()` function in the companion object is how I create them.

```java
class Feature1NavHostFragment
@Inject
constructor(
    private val feature1FragmentFactory: Feature1FragmentFactory
): NavHostFragment(){

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        ((activity?.application) as BaseApplication)
            .getAppComponent()
            .feature1Component()
            .create()
            .inject(this)
        childFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = feature1FragmentFactory
        super.onAttach(context)
    }

    companion object{

        const val KEY_GRAPH_ID = "android-support-nav:fragment:graphId"

        @JvmStatic
        fun create(
            feature1FragmentFactory: Feature1FragmentFactory,
            @NavigationRes graphId: Int = 0
        ): Feature1NavHostFragment{
            var bundle: Bundle? = null
            if(graphId != 0){
                bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putInt(KEY_GRAPH_ID, graphId)
            }
            val result = Feature1NavHostFragment(feature1FragmentFactory)
            if(bundle != null){
                result.arguments = bundle
            }
            return result
        }
    }

}
```

---

**MainActivity.kt**

This is an example of how I create the `NavHostFragment`'s in MainActivity.

```java
val newNavHostFragment = Feature1NavHostFragment.create(
                                  getFeature1FragmentFactory(),
                                  graphId
                         )
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(
        R.id.main_nav_host_container,
        newNavHostFragment,
        getString(R.string.NavHostFragmentTag)
    )
    .setPrimaryNavigationFragment(newNavHostFragment)
    .commit()
```

---

**Feature1MainFragment.kt**

And here is an example of how I'm navigating to other fragments in the graph.

```java
btn_go_next.setOnClickListener {
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_feature1MainFragment_to_feature1NextFragment)
}
```

---

## Summary

Like I said, in every fragment I'm printing the backstack for both the `ChildFragmentManager` and the `SupportFragmentManager`. Both have a constant size of one. It's as if the fragments are being replaced as I navigate into the graph instead of added to the stack.

Anyways, thanks for reading this and I would appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a misunderstanding on my part (and a bug, also on my part).

If you loop through the fragments in the `childFragmentManager` it only ever shows the top-most fragment for some reason.

**Example**

```java
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentByTag(getString(R.string.NavHostFragmentTag)) as NavHostFragment
val fragments = navHostFragment.childFragmentManager.fragments
for(fragment in fragments){
    // Only prints a single fragment, no matter the backstack size
}
```

However, if you print the backstack size like this, you will get the correct answer.

```java
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentByTag(getString(R.string.NavHostFragmentTag)) as NavHostFragment
val backstackCount = navHostFragment.childFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount
println("backstack count: $backstackCount")
```

---

At the end of the day this misunderstanding caused me to believe the fragments were not being added to the backstack. All is good.